# Windows 10 can't be installed on my ssd

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, ssd, multi-boot, bootloader

I bought ssd yesterday (Intel ssd 5). I installed ssd instead of CDROM.

First I tried install Ubuntu which is my primary OS. It works fine. I manually create all partitions and then system works.

Then I want install windows 10, but the problem is that Windows 10 always create boot partition on my old harddisk. I need installed windows bootloader on the same disk because then there is not working dual boot and windows 10 restart or shutdown doesn't work. Screen comes black but laptop is still running.

If I want create install on partition on ssd, windows 10 installer says that Windows 10 can't be installed on this partition. For more information look for logs.

I tried to create partition from Windows 10 installer. I can see there my Ubuntu partitions and newly created partition for Windows 10 but Windows are not able install bootloader on ssd partition.

Is it possible install windows 10 bootloader on ssd disk. And if yes what I need to do to achieve this.

**EDITED**

[Picture how Windows 10 creates partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kxk2u.png)

Thanks for replies.

Comment: My guess is is ubuntu's formatted the disk to MBR - http://superuser.com/questions/1005392/installing-windows-10-windows-cant-be-installed-on-mbr-convert-to-gpt . Its typically a good idea to install windows then linux unless you mean they're on seperate drives

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used diskpart commands to formatted disks back to gpt. Then I installed windows 10 first but the Windows 10 again creates 500 MB partition (reserving for system) on old HDD and now he can't shutdown again. What I have to do to install Windows 10 only on one disk (new ssd). I added picture how partitions look now.

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect the old disk. Clean out the new disk, and install windows 10 on that. You can could in theory select the boot device from the bios/UEFI bootloader.

You could then update grub ([os-prober](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup#Scripts:_.2Fetc.2Fgrub.d.2F) would detect the windows partition) or edit the bcd with an appropriate tool (I use easybcd) to load either OS from one bootloader. When I did it (with both OSes installed alone), linux automatically picked up the windows partition.