# Ubuntu - How to convert GPT to MBR?

Tags: ubuntu

I want to convert GPT to MBR, here's the reason why:

Recently, I had Windows 8.1, I was thinking to download the .ISO file from Official Microsoft website and reinstall Windows 8.1, and I did. I booted the USB and saw that my laptop (Lenovo B590) was ignoring it, it was just booting to Windows.

I just realized that my disk was GPT, not MBR, and that's the problem. Ubuntu was installed fine, but Windows didn't. 
I formatted my C:/ drive, just to check if anything works. Nothing did. When I formatted my C:/ drive, I had no OS. And I always got the "Your PC needs to be repaired" notification when I turned my PC on. So I just installed Ubuntu so I can fix the problem.

Please give me detailed answers, I want to convert my GPT disk to MBR.

Back to the story, I realized that I can't install any Windows.

Please, I really need answers about the following:

1. Can I install Windows 8.1 on GPT, if yes then how?
2. If the above question's answer is "no", then how can I convert my GPT disk to MBR, in able to install Windows?

Update:  My boot order is correct. I booted the USB with Rufus, my USB is 32GB.

Comment: Windows 8.1 supports GPT.  You simply install it like you would install any version of Windows.  This sounds like a problem with your boot order and/or the media not being created the correct way.  Update your question to include infomration on the installation media your using and how it was created.

Comment: @Ramhound Question is updated.

Comment: So you used FAT32 to create your Installation media?  Anything else won’t work in a case like this.  I suggest using the Windows 8.1 Media Creation Tool instead.

Comment: Rufus is a boot USB creator, thus **it doesn't and can't boot your computer in any way**. Both your questions already have duplicates here. While creating the pendrive with Rufus you need to choose the target system as UEFI. If Windows was booted in BIOS mode then it won't install to a GPT drive. [Windows 10 Can't Install from USB Disk to UEFI](https://superuser.com/q/1013953/241386), [I'm unable to boot my Windows 10 installer USB in UEFI mode?](https://superuser.com/q/840578/241386), [Windows can't be installed on MBR](https://superuser.com/q/1005392/241386#comment1391678_1005392)

Comment: And there are various ways to convert GPT to MBR witout data loss if you've entered that phrase in Google, like [`gdisk` in Linux](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html), [Aomei](https://www.easeus.com/partition-master/convert-gpt-disk-to-mbr-disk.html), [Easus](https://www.easeus.com/partition-master/convert-gpt-disk-to-mbr-disk.html) or [Partition Wizard](https://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html). See [Converting between GPT and MBR without losing data](https://superuser.com/q/1250895/241386). But this isn't the solution to your question which is an XY problem

Comment: Both Rufus and Media Creation Tool only run on Windows.  Just use Rufus and configure it correctly which is already documented in an existing comment

Comment: @Ramhound I installed Windows 7. Now I want to install Windows 8.1 but same issue occur. My Rufus settings:  Partition scheme : GPT. Format as : FAT32. Windows 7 was installed fine but now Windows 8.1 isn't. Do I need to format the USB as NTFS?

Comment: @Ramhound I also tried to run the setup.exe that was in my booted USB in Windows 7, it showed me a error. So please guide me. Help me install Windows 8.1

Comment: help me please, with my new statement

Comment: Nvm, solved. That's it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution worked for me. I realized that the ISO file had the problem.

Downloading the Windows 8.1 ISO file again did the trick!

Here's what you need to do:

1. Boot your USB with Rufus (correct settings)
2. Run 'setup.exe' located in your USB's storage when its booted.
3. If setup.exe runs without errors, then the USB is fine. If it does have a error like "xx.file is corrupted, missing or in unknown format" then it's the ISO that's creating the mess. Downloading a new ISO file from the official site will fix it.
4. If setup.exe runs without errors and you are still unable to boot, try changing the BIOS mode to UEFI, turning off Safe Boot and / or quick boot.

Comment: What solution? Answering your own question is completely acceptable, but you should put in the steps and processes you used to fix the issue.

Comment: @acejavelin There you go. Edited.